# SQL Server (increase number)

Tags: sql

i have 1 table called  `tbl_Run` and only 1 column called `wo`.the question is how can i do every times

i update the number will increase + 1.it will replace and replace..example current no is 4 then when i doing 1st update it will change to 5, 2nd update 6 then 7 bla bla bla..

```
UPDATE tbl_Run

Set wo=
```

?

Comment: Does it just have one row too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl_Run
SET wo = ISNULL(wo, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To increment the value on every row you can do:

```
UPDATE tbl_Run
SET wo=wo+1
WHERE wo IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a build in function for this but i don't know it, i would use an sql subquery to fetch the current updatenumber and set is to that value + 1.